# ports which are open but appear closed

Tags: iptables

I was wondering if anybody can help. Is it possbile to have a specific port open on a VPS but if you check it using a TCP checker it appears closed or unreachable? If it is possible, how would one go about doing this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. If the VPS is behind a firewall that doesn'r expose the port or ports on the VPS to the outside.

Comment: thanks. I do have firewall up on the VPS. I was just wondering as I had a node for a cryptocurrency which uses a specific. On my VPS IP address this port is open and on a TCP checker site it shows as open and connected. However, other nodes are showing this port as closed and unreachable, yet still 'communicating' with the network and wondering why this is and how they did it. Sorry, I realise this might not be the correct place for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. Are you hoping to connect to the port for something, but hide that it's open?

If a service is running and has an open port (SSH for example on port 22), you can't 'hide' this port to port scanners and still expect to be able to connect with an SSH client. There are tricks to this like port-knocking, but that's beyond the scope of how to do here.

If you have port 22 open, but don't want things to connect to it (or limit who can) then you would need to use a firewall to control the access. This could be allowing only local network, specific IP's etc.

There are some other things one can do, but that is also beyond the scope of this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't notice the OP clarification. Leaving old answer as it might help others.

This app might be communicating over udp, make sure to check that.

---

This is a good case for [knockd](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock), which is a little daemon, that listens for all connections interface level and if a configured sequence of ports is connected to, it will run a specific command. So it's possible to hide your daemon behind the firewall and open only for specific IPs.

That still leaves the issue of unencrypted traffic going over the internet.

Another solution would be ssh port forwarding.